# Como configurar o plugin WP Super Cache?

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Recentemente instalei o plugin WP Super Cache em um blog WordPress. Em todos os tutorias que achei para configurar ele, dizem que a melhor opção na aba avançado é usar o modo: "Use mod_rewrite to serve cache files"

Mas quando escolhi essa opção, algo estranho está acontecendo. Todas as páginas estão sendo servidas em cache como o plugin promete fazer.

Mas a pagina inicial, Home não está segurando o cache, sempre que ela é atualizada um novo cache é criado, e sobrecarregando o servidor.

Como podem a ver na imagem ao contrario do que vários tutorias dizem, o plugin está dizendo que a opção recomendada é: Use PHP to serve cache files.

Como é a maneira certa de configurar esse plugin?

[image]

Comment: Já conferiu o [FAQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/faq/) do plugin? Tem muita coisa lá... A ferramenta de busca no WP.org é horrorosa, mas talvez ache alguma coisa por aqui: https://wordpress.org/search/mod_rewrite+wp-super-cache?forums=1